# rowBody refresh loosing the inner grid, on editing the main grid row. extjs 3.. can i re-render the inner grid..?

Tags: gridview, grid, extjs3

I am using `enablerowbody:true` , inserting a `div` inside rowBody, using `getRowClass`, and rendering a grid inside this div. Initially its loading fine (grid inside grid),

But the problem arises when i am editing the main row content, after which, the `getRowClass` firing again, causing recreation of the `div`, hence loosing the rendered grid..

How to re-render the inner grid OR avoid recreation of the div..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As saki suggested, Create the innerGrid as

```
record.innerGrid=new Ext.grid.GridPanel();
```

and then re-render the innerGrid on rowupdated listener of `gridView`.

`listeners:{
    rowupdated:function( view, firstRow, record ){
        var tools=record.innerGrid.tools;
        record.innerGrid.rendered=false;
        record.innerGrid.tools=null;
        record.innerGrid.render(Ext.get('rowBodyDivId'));
        record.innerGrid.tools=tools;
    }
}`

NOTE:Holds True only in case when inner grid is not editable ..

still trying for Editable innerGrid (attached/fired events are throwing error)

Comment: Here you might find the solution with firing events from the inner grid http://blogs.walkingtree.in/2015/06/30/nested-grid-in-sencha-ext-js/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the default behavior, unfortunately. You need to listen to [beforerefresh](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView-event-beforerefresh) event of the grid view and move inner grids' element(s) to a safe place, for example append to document body but invisible, in the listener.

Then, in [refresh](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView-event-refresh) event, you must move the inner grid(s) back to outer grid rowBody.

You shouldn't just recreate the inner grids w/o proper destroying to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: i did, `record.innerGrid=new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel`. so i am having the component but invisible.. thing is ,i am not able to move it to back to outer grid rowBody. how to do it..?
i tried
record.InnerGrid.render(Ext.get('divId')); and
      record.innerGrid.getView().refresh();

Comment: You need to work on elements level. Method [Ext.Element.appendChild](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-appendChild) should be all you need.